# How to use $add inside the update() function in Mongo?

Tags: function, mongodb

I'm trying to update this document;

```
{"dealId" : 201, "commitCount" : 3 }
```

...I just need to increment `commitCount` by 1, so I'm trying to use the add[] function inside update(), but I can't get it to work...

```
db.deal.update( {dealId:201},{$set:{commitCount:{$add:['$commitCount',1]} }} )
```

the error I get from Mongo is `not okForStorage`, no idea what that means, the field does not get updated,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That error means you're trying to use a field name which is invalid in MongoDB -- that would be either a field name with a dot (".") in it, or a field name containing a dollar sign.

`$set` is used to replace a field in its entirety, so what you have above is saying "replace the contents of the `commitCount` field with the document `{$add: ['$commitCount', 1]}`", which is an invalid document.

To atomically increment or decrement a field's value (assuming the field's current value is a number) use the `$inc` modifier:

```
db.deal.update({dealId: 201}, {$inc: {commitCount: 1}})
```

Comment: `$inc`, too easy, worked great, also worked in findAndModify(), thanks for the help